# Calculating the inverse Laplace transform of the following

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I'm given that $$F(s)=\frac{a+3s-6}{(s-2)^2+a^2}$$ and I want to calculate $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s))$$

My attempt at the solution is as follows:

First splitting $F(s)$ as follows $$F(s)=\frac{a}{(s-2)^{2}+a^{2}}+\frac{3(s-2)}{(s-2)^2+a^{2}}$$

Then I need to calculate $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{a}{(s-2)^{2}+a^{2}})+\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\frac{3(s-2)}{(s-2)^{2}+a^{2}})$$

Now I know that $$\mathcal{L}(\sin(at))=\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$$. However we have a $(s-2)^{2}$ on the denominator of $F(s)$, how would I deal with this to find the correct function?.Would someone please show me how this would be done?

Thanks for taking the time to read through this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I know the solution should be $$f(t)=e^{2t}sin(at)+3e^{2t}cos(at)$$
But i'm unsure where the exponential terms come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html), the idea is

$$
L\left\{e^{at}\sin(bt) \right\} = \frac{b}{(s-a)^2+b^2}
$$

and

$$
L\left\{e^{at}\cos(bt) \right\} = \frac{s-a}{(s-a)^2+b^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

What does an $e^t$ factor do to a Laplace transform?

Suppose:

$\mathcal L\{f(t)\} = \int_0^{\infty} f(t)e^{-st}\ dt = F(s)$

And we want to find:$\mathcal L\{e^{at}f(t)\}$

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{at} f(t)e^{-st}\ dt\\
\int_0^{\infty} f(t)e^{-(s-a)t}\ dt\\
F(s-a)$

Coming the other way we have:

$\mathcal L\{\sin at\} = F(s) = \frac {a}{s^2 +a^2}\\
\mathcal L\{e^{2t}\sin at\} = F(s-2) = \frac {a}{(s-2)^2 +a^2}\\
\mathcal L\{\cos at\}  = \frac {s}{s^2 +a^2}\\
\mathcal L\{e^{2t}\cos at\}  = \frac {s-2}{(s-2)^2 +a^2}\\
$

Comment: Ahh thank you this makes more sense now, its just the shifting property?

Comment: Shouldn't the sign of $a^2$ in the denominator positive?